# Weka libsvm is not in classpath after system format

Tags: weka, libsvm

While using weka SVM ,the error is receiving "libsvm is not in classpath'.
I set the classpath through environmental variables, But the error still remains.I was using the weka svm for one year for data classification, but I haven't gone through this kind of problem. This problem surfaced when I have installed weka 3.6.12 after formatting my system. I am using window 7 32-bit PC. The error "jdbc.idbDriver  is not in path" is also exists.

Answer (score 0):

Open SimpleCLI in your weka GUI and execute following commands.

```
java weka.core.SystemInfo
```

Please look for following values

```
java.class.path: ./weka.jar; 
... 
weka.version: 3.6.13
```

As you can see, I do not have libsvm.jar in my classpath too.
I have to include using one of the ways explained in http://weka.wikispaces.com/LibSVM.

Below passage is taken from (http://weka.wikispaces.com/LibSVM Troubleshooting)

## Troubleshooting

- libsvm classes not in CLASSPATH!◦Check whether the libsvm.jar is really in your CLASSPATH. Execute the following command in the SimpleCLI:
  java weka.core.SystemInfo
  The property java.class.path must list the libsvm.jar. If it is listed, check whether the path is correct.
  If you're on Windows and you find %CLASSPATH% there, see next bullet point to fix this.
- On Windows, if you added the libsvm.jar to your CLASSPATH environment variable, it can still happen that Weka pops up the error message that the libsvm classes are not in your CLASSPATH. This can happen on Windows 2000 and XP and the %CLASSPATH% does not get expanded to its actual value in starting up Weka. You can inspect your current CLASSPATH with which Weka got started up with the SimpleCLI (see previous bullet point). If %CLASSPATH% is listed there, your system has the same problem. This Wekalist post explains how to explicitly add the mysql.jar to RunWeka.ini (works the same for libsvm.jar).
  Note: backslashes have to be escaped, not only once, but twice (they get interpreted by Java twice!). In other words, instead of one you have to use four: C:\some\where then turns into C:\\some\\where.

Answer (score 0):

Write a startscript that sets up everything for you.

The file could be called `weka.bat` und should look like this (untested- adapt as necessary):

```
WEKA_HOME=c:\weka
set WEKA_JAR=%WEKA_HOME%\weka.jar
set PATH=$WEKA_HOME;$PATH
set CP="%WEKA_JAR%;%WEKA_HOME%\lib\libsvm.jar"
set DIR=c:\weka\data
cd "%DIR%"
set WEKA_HOME=%DIR%
rem start small GUI Chooser
java -cp $CP weka.gui.GUIChooser 2 >>c:\weka\weka.log
```

This assumes that you installed weka to a dir called c:\weka,
that the subdirectories \data and \lib exist, and that you have copied libsvm.jar into the \lib subdirectory.